# How to send selected value from dropdown list to database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

So I'm creating an application where I can create a new group with a name, a dropdown list to add a member, a minimum age, a maximum age, and whether the group is active or not.

However I'm getting the validation error 'member is required' when I'm choosing a member from my dropdown list, and when I choose a member from my dropdown list I want it to be sent to the database and added to the new group I just created together with the all other input values.

Here is my dropdown code:

```
<x-tmk.form.select wire:model="newGroup.member_id" id="member_id" class="block mt-1 w-full">
    <option value="">Select a member</option>
    @foreach ($members as $member)
        <option value="{{ $member->id }}">{{ $member->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</x-tmk.form.select>
```

Here is my controller code to create a new group:

```
public function createGroup()
{
    $this->validate();
    $group = Group::create([
        'id' => $this->newGroup['id'],
        'name' => $this->newGroup['name'],
        'member_id' => $this->newGroup['member_id'],
        'min_age' => $this->newGroup['min_age'],
        'max_age' => $this->newGroup['max_age'],
        'active' => $this->newGroup['active'],
    ]);
    $group->groupmember()->create([
        'member_id' => $this->newGroup['member_id'],
    ]);
    $this->showModal = false;
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('swal:toast', [
        'background' => 'success',
        'html' => "The group <b><i>{$group->name}</i></b> has been added",
    ]);
}
```

And here is my controller code for my `render()` method:

```
public function render()
{
    $members = Member::orderBy('name')->get();

    $query = Group::orderBy('id');

    if ($this->search) {
        $groups = $query->searchGroupName($this->search)->paginate($this->perPage);
    } else {
        if ($this->showActiveOnly) {
            $groups = $query->where('active', 1)->paginate($this->perPage);
        } else {
            $groups = $query->where('active', 0)->paginate($this->perPage);
        }
    }

    return view('livewire.admin.group-classification', compact('groups', 'members'))
        ->layout('layouts.projectphp-layout', [
            'title' => 'Groepen',
            'description' => 'Hier kan je de groep indelingen bekijken.'
        ]);
}
```

I'm using Laravel 9.52 and PHP 8.1

Comment: post your validation rules in question or try changing `$this->newGroup['member_id']` to `$this->newGroup->member_id`

Comment: these are my validation rule `protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'newGroup.name' => 'required|unique:groups,name',
            'newGroup.member_id' => 'required|exists:members,id',
            'newGroup.min_age' => 'required|numeric|min:0|unique:groups,min_age',
            'newGroup.max_age' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'newGroup.active' => 'required',
        ];
    }`

Comment: Did above solution work?

Comment: nope, i still get the validation error 'member is required'

Comment: debug with `dd($this);` in your `createGroup()` function and check what you are getting member id or not, maybe you need to add default values in `mount()` or in fillable in your model

Comment: i get "member_id" => null for my newGroup array

Comment: See my answer hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Livewire does not listen to `selected` attributes in HTML when you are using `wire:model`, because it will overwrite it with the value from the component. Therefor, set `wire:key` to your `option` like below,

```
<x-tmk.form.select wire:model="newGroup.member_id" id="member_id" class="block mt-1 w-full">
    <option value="">Select a member</option>
    @foreach ($members as $member)
        <option value="{{ $member->id }}" wire:key="member-{{ $member->id }}">{{ $member->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</x-tmk.form.select>
```

To set a value that is bound through `wire:model`, you need to set the value in the component. So in the `mount()` method, you can do

```
$this->newGroup['member_id'] = $member->id;
```

Comment: when i add that line in my `mount()` method, it says 'undefined variable $member'

Comment: btw when i change the select tag to an input field, it does register the name but not when i select something from the dropdown list

Comment: add default value 0 in place of $member->id in mount @Brent

Comment: still getting the same 'null' value